# jest.fn() mocked function wasn't called for the second time

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm testing one of our project's function and encountered a strange issue, I'm out of ideas how to solve this.

```sh
jest -v
24.8.0
node -v
v10.14.2
```

```
    const action = (fn1, fn2) => {
        fn1('fn1 call 1');

        return fn2('fn2 call 1')
            .then(() => {
                fn1('fn1 call 2');
                console.log('then was called');
            });
    };

    describe('test case', () => {
        it('should pass', () => {
            const fn1 = jest.fn();
            const fn2 = jest.fn()
                .mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve('test'));

            action(fn1, fn2);

            expect(fn2).toBeCalledWith('fn2 call 1');
            expect(fn1).nthCalledWith(1,'fn1 call 1');
            expect(fn1).nthCalledWith(2,'fn1 call 2');
        })
    });
```

output:

```
  ● test case › should pass

    expect(jest.fn()).nthCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function second call to have been called with:
      ["fn1 call 2"]
    But it was not called.

      19 |             expect(fn2).toBeCalledWith('fn2 call 1');
      20 |             expect(fn1).nthCalledWith(1,'fn1 call 1');
    > 21 |             expect(fn1).nthCalledWith(2,'fn1 call 2');
         |                         ^
      22 |         })
      23 |     });
      24 | 

      at Object.nthCalledWith (test.js:21:25)

  console.log test.js:7
    then was called
```

If I replace fn1 with:
`(args) => console.log(args)`

I get this:

```
  console.log test.js:13
    fn1 call 1

  console.log test.js:13
    fn1 call 2

  console.log test.js:7
    then was called
```

So, probably, there is some error with how I use `jest.fn()`
Could anyone help my with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are receiving this error is that `action` returns a promise and you are not waiting for the result of that promise; when `fn1` is called the second time your test has failed due to this line `expect(fn1).nthCalledWith(2, 'fn1 call 2')`, hence the error you see. Also, calling `Promise.resolve('test')` in `jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();` is redundant [see doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue)

To fix this you need to wait for the result of `action`:

```
describe('test case', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const fn1 = jest.fn();
    const fn2 = jest.fn()
      .mockResolvedValue('test');

    await action(fn1, fn2);

    expect(fn2)
      .toBeCalledWith('fn2 call 1');
    expect(fn1)
      .nthCalledWith(1, 'fn1 call 1');
    expect(fn1)
      .nthCalledWith(2, 'fn1 call 2');
  });
});
```

Another approach:

```
describe('test case', () => {
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    const fn1 = jest.fn();
    const fn2 = jest.fn()
      .mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve('test'));

    action(fn1, fn2)
      .then(() => {
        expect(fn2)
          .toBeCalledWith('fn2 call 1');
        expect(fn1)
          .nthCalledWith(1, 'fn1 call 1');
        expect(fn1)
          .nthCalledWith(2, 'fn1 call 2');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```